# Error in getting data from Oracle to hive using sqoop

Tags: oracle, hive, bigdata, sqoop

I am running the following sqoop query:

```
sqoop import  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:389/ewsop000,cn=OracleContext,dc=****,dc=com \
--table ngprod.ewt_payment_ng  --where "d_last_updt_ts >= to_timestamp('11/01/2013 11:59:59.999999 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')" \
AND "d_last_updt_ts <= to_timestamp('11/10/2013 11:59:59.999999 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')"  --username ***** --P \
--columns N_PYMNT_ID,D_last_updt_Ts,c_pymnt_meth,c_rcd_del,d_Create_ts \
--hive-import  --hive-table payment_sample_table2
```

The schema  for table payment_sample_table2 is in hive. it is running fine if I do not use

```
 AND "d_last_updt_ts <= to_timestamp('11/10/2013 11:59:59.999999 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM')"
```

Can someone tell me why, or if there's any other way to get the range of data?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the exact error .  In any case please put the "AND .." within the same double quotation and on the same previous line as the preceding part of the "where" clause. As shown above you have a badly formatted commandline - nothing to do with the actual query.